# How to handle a long-running shell script run from web form

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a web interface for basic data input to run a simulation. These inputs modify a data file which is used in some physics simulations which take a long time (> 10 minutes). It will produce a graph and a mp4 video of the simulation. I'm pretty inexperienced with HTML/PHP, so I'm not sure of what the best way to deal with this is.

I was thinking of somehow creating a page which updates with each step in the simulation (tail the output file and somehow output that to the page as an indication of progress). But I don't know how to handle the user closing the page or if the session is closed (the work is still run on the background, just no access).

Any thoughts/advice?

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound like a classical use-case for PHP..
Anyhow there are some options you should consider:

- Run a PHP script (web-page) which starts a thread and forces it to keep alive (which is a really bad idea)
- Write a PHP backend (some script) which you can run with your shell

  - You need to seperate between front- and backend
  - Memcached could suit your cache
- Write a service in Python/C/Bash which can communicate with a frontend

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP page that modifies the simulation parameters and starts the simulation (unless it is already running). Each time this PHP page is invoked, let it display the latest status of the simulation (at the time of request). Once the page has already been rendered, use AJAX to periodically poll the server for updates on the simulation.

Basically, the PHP page should never hang. It should always provide an immediate status of the simulation and complete. It will be up to the periodic AJAX poll to provide updates to the user. This also means that the user can refresh the page without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

What not to do: make everything in a typical PHP file (perhaps with included files). Your user will open the page and their web browser will appear to be frozen for 10 minutes. Worse, many browsers have a 60 second timeout; still worse, PHP has a default 30 second timeout.

Instead, use some sort of asynchronous processing. Here's the strategy I would recommend: create a front-end in PHP/JavaScript and a back-end in the language of your choice.

- The frontend will initiate the PHP `exec()` command, which runs the command in a shell. Format it like this:

  ```
  exec("command path/to/script &")
  ```

  The ampersand runs the command in the background. Command can be PHP, Python, Java... the language is up to you!
- Your backend program will periodically write it's progress to some sort of temporary progress file.
- Your frontend webpage will periodically communicate with AJAX to get progress. When it completes, it will go to a new PHP page that loads the output.